# Why the stylesheet link path changed when I deploy the rails app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So in my localhost the stylesheet application.css is referenced as `/assets/application.css` and everything is fine, but when I deployed the app to Heroku, the css file is requested at the location `/stylesheets/application.css`. Is there something I didn't config right? I am just using `stylesheet_link_tag "applicaiton"` in my code.
Update, I actually got:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/assets/application.css");

How does this happen, the file is right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might not have the right stack on Heroku. You current stack doesn't support rails 3.1 and doesn't support Assets pipeline either.

To fix this you would need to switch to the Cedar stack: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

Comment: It doesn't help either, take look at my app, github.com/baboonworksfine/simple-chat

Comment: problem solved, my app's asset pipeline module is not loaded properly

Comment: @baboonWorksFine can you detail more how you got this working? I am facing the same problem